# Control external monitor which do not implement DDC/CI properly

Tags: monitors

I have an HP Compaq monitor. It works fine, except that it doesn't support the DDC/CI protocol, even when DDC/CI support is enabled from its OSD menu. Running `ddcutil detect` command tells that it is an invalid display. I can do other things such as reading the I2C addresses and reading EDID of that monitor. DDC/CI also works if I plug another monitor in place of the HP one.

My suspicion is that the monitor has DDC/CI support, but on a non-standard slave address. How to manually probe the I2C slave addresses for traces of DDC/CI? Or is there any other way other than DDC/CI?

Comment: Notice for non-Indian readers: Compaq ceased to exist for most of the world in 2013, yes. (technically, Compaq ceased to exist in 2002, but was HP continued to use it for low-end systems until 2013.) But the brand continues to be used in the Brazilian and Indian market, according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compaq).

Comment: hey, puspam, how do your know that you have DDC/CI and not the slighly less archaic E-DDC? Or is this *really* a VGA monitor??

Comment: Re: *on a non-standard slave address.* I've never seen a screen on anything other than the standard address; that's simply because it's a standard address for a very cheap family of EEPROMs. This feels very unlikely, unless you have physically seen the I²C lines on the PCB going into a component that looks like a memory chip.

Comment: @MarcusMüller According to the monitor's OSD menu, it has DDC. I can't understand what you mean by "really a VGA monitor", but its connector is VGA.

Comment: I'm just surprised, haven't seen such a monitor in decades